# Difference between address in VTABLE and direct address take

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void f1()
    {
        cout << "Foo::f1()" << endl;
    }
    virtual void f2()
    {
        cout << "Foo::f2()" << endl;
    }
    virtual void f3()
    {
        cout << "Foo::f3()" << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    typedef void(*MethodFoo_f)();

    Foo* ptr = new Foo();

    cout << "Object address: " << ptr << endl;
    cout << "__vfptr: " << (int*)*((int*)ptr) << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        int* e = (int*)*((int*)ptr) + i;
        cout << "Address from __vfptr " << e;
        auto t = &Foo::f1;
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0: t = &Foo::f1; cout << ", address from main " << (void*&)t << "  ";  break;
            case 1: t = &Foo::f2; cout << ", address from main " << (void*&)t << "  ";  break;
            case 2: t = &Foo::f3; cout << ", address from main " << (void*&)t << "  ";  break;

        }
        cout << "execute: ";
        auto func = (MethodFoo_f*)(e);
        (*func)();
    }

}
```

Hi all, can you explain me: why we can see difference in addresses of same method's.

Example output for Visual Studio

> Object address: 007ADE28
>   __vfptr: 00E63B34
>
> Address from __vfptr 00E63B34, address from main 00E51F23  execute:
>   Foo::f1()
>
> Address from __vfptr 00E63B38, address from main 00E51F1E  execute:
>   Foo::f2()
>
> Address from __vfptr 00E63B3C, address from main 00E51F19  execute:
>   Foo::f3()

If VTABLE call transforme to

```
objPointer->(__vfptr + methodIndex)()
```

Why in table, we hold modified values of addresses ?

Comment: The way vtables are implemented (if used at all) are compiler specific. What would you expect actually? _"`objPointer->(__vfptr + methodIndex)()`"_ Where is such stated in the c++ standards? Also check pointer arithmetics, `+` might mean something different as you expect here.

Comment: Everything seems fine. Explain your *reasoning* why you expect something else to happen.

Comment: I suggest you first understand what a pointer to virtual member function is (and what it is not). For example, it is not convertable to pointer to non-member.

Comment: You seem to be making a lot of assumptions about the underlying implementation, creating seriously undefined behavior.  But the platform you then tested on is a perfect fit for all your apparent assumptions.  Everything happens just as one would expect based on those assumptions.  Then for reasons you really didn't make clear, you don't like that output.

Comment: If you really want to understand how it is implemented on this specific platform/compiler, you can look to the produced assembler code

Comment: I am not sure, but the compiler may have optimized the code and remove VTABLE and pointer to it; since there are no inherited classes. You may try to switch optimizations off

Comment: Is there any output from the last 3 statements (        cout << "execute: ";
        auto func = (MethodFoo_f*)(e);
        (*func)(); ? Does the program crash or exit normally?

Comment: According to your logic, it should be `int* e = (int*)*((int*)ptr+i);` instead of
        `int* e = (int*)*((int*)ptr) + i;`. However it does not explain why the address is different for `i==0`

Comment: @AndrejAdamenko  `(int*)ptr` is the address of the object as if the object were an array of `int`.  The original `*((int*)ptr)` is the 32-bit vtable pointer as an `int` so `(int*)*((int*)ptr) + i` was correct for the address of a position in the vtable.  Your suggestion of `*((int*)ptr+i)` for nonzero `i` pulls other 32-bit quantities from the original object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally realized what you wanted, you are missing one level of indirection.

`ptr` points to the object
(assuming 32 bit and many other things you shouldn't really assume):
`*((int*)ptr)` is the address of the vtable
`(int*)*((int*)ptr)` is `*((int**)ptr)` is a cast of that same address
`(int*)*((int*)ptr)+i` is `& (*((int**)ptr))[i]` is a position within the vtable and you wanted the contents of that position:
`*((int*)*((int*)ptr)+i)` or `(*((int**)ptr))[i]`

You have that extra level of indirection instead in `func`
`MethodFoo_f` is the type of a pointer to the function and `func` is a pointer to `MethodFoo_f`
So the numbers you expect to be the same for each function were a pointer to pointer to function and a simple pointer to function.

I still wouldn't guess the pointer to function you get from `auto t = &Foo::f1;` reliably has the same contents as a `void*` to the actual code of the function.  But at least with the correct levels of indirection you would be comparing it to that.